# fixed actionbar across all activities

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

How do I keep my actionbar fixed across all activities? Whenever i launch a new intent, the above actionbar will refresh. How do i keep it fixed as I navigate around the page? (only those below actionbar will change)
I have declared my actionitems in the layout.xml and use actionbarsherlock for my actionbar.

Thanks!

Comment: disable animation between your activities.

Comment: the actionbar is created for each activity. If you don't want that, you should use fragments and/or viewpager to change only the content bellow your ActionBar.

Comment: How do I go about using fragments? Does that mean I need to replace the different activities with fragments or actionbar become fragment? Sorry for the noob qns. I am rather new at android development.